# how to display the rate at which requests are being received over a certain time interval in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

right now this widget reports the number of responses given by the the API as a cumulative amount. Because of this, differences in the rate is not immediately clear. How to change the graph to display the rate? eg: at 10am-4pm the request I got is 1000, 4pm-10pm is 500, it go up and down, not cumulative.

This is right now
[image]

This is Prometheus endpoints:

```
# HELP get_tax_requests_seconds Response latency(seconds) of gRPC.
# TYPE get_tax_requests_seconds histogram
get_tax_requests_seconds{m_application="adapter-mvp",method = "GetData", m_env="test",quantile="0.5",} 0.0
```

After I add rate, it shows like this, not the number of request

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [rate](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) function, like in the following example:

```
sum(rate(get_tax_requests_seconds_count{<labels>}[1h])) * 60 * 60
```

Comment: Hi, after I add rate, it shows like above

Comment: The rate function calculates the per-second rate, so it's better to multiply by 3600 if you want the per-hour rate or 86400 if you want the per-day rate.